# PulseAudio Equalizer randomly stops functioning

Tags: linux, linux-mint, kde, pulse-audio, equalizer

My problem is just as the title says. I'm using Linux Mint KDE 17.3. The only predictability that I can get from it is that it shuts off when everything goes silent for at least a second, but that happens only like 50% of the time, other times it stays intact.

If I leave the PC for a longer period of time, let's say at least 1 minute has passed, it's always off. Does anyone know what might be to blame for this?

Answer (score -1):

I was having the same problem, and I solved it with the fourth response in this post:
https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=309&t=135958

It shows how to set the pulseaudio-equalizer device as the default in the system, wich solved the issue.

Comment: Please *post* the answer here.

Comment: Consider adding and quoting the content from the link to your answer supporting what specifically is helpful in case the link ever goes bad—I know that never happens right, an Internet link going bad say what.